# Display both sale price and original price

Tags: bigcartel

In bigcartel, is there anyway to have products that are on sale show their original price as well. something like ($̶2̶0̶.̶0̶0̶) $16.00 
I'm sure there is some type of code or way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently a way within the Big Cartel admin to specifically set a sale price (in addition to the original price) so unfortunately something like this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: it actually is possible, I just don't know how to do it. I've seen it done.

Comment: @DanielRevenkov Big Cartel doesn't offer the ability to set two different prices (sale price and original price) - you can only just mark items on sale. Other stores may have written in some complex coding to display sale prices, but that is a lengthy process and is specific to their needs.